# 8 bit serial to parallel shifter in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I programmed an 8-bit shifter in vhdl:

```vhdl
entity 8b is 
  port(s, clk : in std_logic; p : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)); 
end entity; 

architecture arch of 8b is 
  Signal iq : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
begin 
  process(clk) 
  begin 
    if rising_edge(clk) then 
      iq(7) <= s;
      iq(6 downto 0) <= iq(7 downto 1); 
    end if; 
  end process; 
  p <= iq; 
end architecture;
```

The idea is that I'm taking input and giving it to my first D-FF.
Then over the next 7 cycles, the other Flip Flops get the other serial inputs which will be given to the parallel output p.

However, I'm not sure if this logic is flawed because this is the solution we got for this exercise:

```vhdl
architecture behavior of 8b is
  signal p_intern : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  P <= p_intern;
  process(CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
      p_intern <= p_intern(6 downto 0) & S;
    end if;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

But I don't get the `p_intern <= p_inter(6 downto 0) & S;` part.

Can someone please explain the logic behind this and if my version is also valid?

Comment: What feedback did you receive when you turned in your solution?

Comment: @mkrieger1 none this is not something we can turn in.

Comment: Okay, I see. As a tip, you should have a simulation with some test cases where you can easily see for yourself if your design is working properly.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't analyse it in gtk wave but I think I understand now. The first bit we put into the serial to parallel shifter will be the first one in the "array". Where as the last one will be in the last place. So we always push the first bit from the shifter out and attach the input to the end. So FiFo basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two implementations seem to be the lines

> ```
> iq(7) <= s;
> iq(6 downto 0) <= iq(7 downto 1);
> ```

vs.

> ```
> p_intern <= p_intern(6 downto 0) & S;
> ```

and that `iq` is named `p_intern`. Let's assume they are both named `iq` for the sake of comparison.

Let's see what they are doing:

The first implementation (yours) assigns to the positions of `iq`:

```
7     6     5     ... 1     0
s     iq(7) iq(6) ... iq(2) iq(1)
```

The second implementation (the solution) assigns

```
7     6     5     ... 1     0
iq(6) iq(5) iq(4) ... iq(0) s
```

Where `iq(6 downto 0) & s` means "concatenate `s` to the right of `iq(6 downto 0)`".

So they are not equivalent. Your implementation shifts in the values from the left, and the solution shifts in the values from the right. Which one is correct depends on the specification (presumably the solution is correct).

Comment: thank's mate. Yeah just what I thought. While they have the FiFo approach mine is FiFo... ; )

Comment: No they are both FIFO. Just in opposite directions.